# Importing JSON data into RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I'm attempting to migrate some data into RavenDB. We have a text file with all the data in JSON format but I don't see a straight forward way to import the data into RavenDB. This data was not created by any RavenDB utility, such as Smuggler or backup, but rather generated by parsing a data dump from another application. The data is the raw JSON, exactly as it's expected for our RavenDB application with the exception of the meta data; there is no metadata.

What is the easiest way to import this data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Write a powershell script to read the json file one line at a time, then just POST `http://localhost:8080/databases/your-db/docs/your-doc-id'